# iOS - Storing login credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I need to store login credentials (username, password and a user id) within my app. I've read that the best way of doing that is using Keychain with a wrapper that simplifies things. However there isn't a "standard" wrapper that works with ARC. I tried some custom wrappers but, because of the lack of documentation, I wasn't able to make them work.

Can you suggest me a solution with an example code? Thanks.

Comment: I use SSKeychain for these tasks. It's on github.

Comment: I've already tried to use it, but I had problems in retrieving the entire SSKeychainQuery object (starting from its service). In particular, I cannot access the properties after fetching the object with "accountsForService" method. Can you write an example code? Thanks!

Comment: I just follow the documentation: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SSKeychain/1.2.1/Classes/SSKeychain.html